# Calculating $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow \infty} \left( (-1)^x \frac{1}{2^{x-1}} \right) $

Tags: calculus, limits

My calculus book states that $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow \infty} (-1^x\frac{1}{2^{x-1}})=0$. However, when verifying the calculation by Wolfram, I get a result that the limit does not exist.

What is the correct answer?

Comment: $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}(-1^x\frac{1}{2^{x-1}})=\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}2\cdot (-\frac{1}{2})^x\to 0$.  It should be well known that $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}r^x$ where $|r|<1$ always goes to zero.

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1063774/limit-of-the-geometric-sequence-rn-with-r-1-is-0) for the proof that $\lim_{n\to \infty} r^n = 0$ for $|r|\lt 1$.

Comment: Notice that for real numbers $(-1)^x$ is defined only when $x = p/q$, where $p,q \in \mathbb Z$ and $q$ is odd.