# Prove: If $|r| < 1$, then $\lim_{n\to \infty }r^n$ = 0.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

Prove: If $|r| < 1$, then $\lim_{n\to \infty} r^n = 0$.

- I know I am supposed to use the fact that $\lim_{n\to \infty} r^n = 0$ iff $\lim_{n\to \infty} |r^n| = 0$. I also know that $|r^n|$ is monotone and that I have to prove it by plugging in a value like 1/2 to show it's decreasing but that is as far as I have gotten. I just do not know how to use those ideas. I am stuck on how to prove that it is monotone and how the proof should look in general. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Something like $0\le|r^{n+1}| = |r^n||r| < |r^n| \cdot 1$?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Limit of the geometric sequence $\{r^n\}$, with $|r| < 1$, is $0$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1063774/limit-of-the-geometric-sequence-rn-with-r-1-is-0)

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to MSE.
this is an idea
$$|r|<1\implies\\
1>|r|>|r^2|>|r^3|>...\geq0$$ for the case of $r^n$ you can rewrite
$$0<r<1 \implies 1>r>r^2>...\geq0\\and\ \\ \text{case 1  }\\-1<r<0\implies 0\geq...>r^{2n+3}>r^{2n+1}>...>r^3>r\\\text{case 2}\\ r^2>r^4>r^6>...>r^{2n}>r^{2n+2}>...\geq0  $$

Comment: But a positive  decreasing seqence does not necessarily converge to zero.

Comment: That just shows it's decreasing.  Not thatt it converges to $0$.

Comment: This can easily be fixed, just writing $|r^{n+1}| = |r| \times |r^n|$, and taking the limit, you get $l=|r| l$ so $l=0$.