# Where am going wrong in finding this limit?

Tags: limits-without-lhopital

I have been asked to find the following limit

$f(x)=(x^{2n}-1)/(x^{2n}+1)$ as n tends to infinity. The answers given are in MCQ type with more than one answer correct.
I'll just write the correct answers.

a)$f(x)=1$,for$|x|>1$ and b) $f(x)=-1$, for $|x|<1$.
I came up with first answer but couldn't with second. Have they taken Left and Right Hand limit? I tried but my answer again came as 1. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $\lim_{n \to \infty}x^n = 0$ if $|x|<1$.

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{x^{2n}-1}{x^{2n}+1}=\frac{0-1}{0+1}=-1$$

Note that $x$ here is fixed.

Comment: Thank you. Is $\lim_{n \to \infty}x^n = 0$ if$|x|<1$, a standard result?

Comment: not sure but it's a commonly used result. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1063923/306553) are some proofs.

Comment: Thanks for providing a link to those proofs. They are helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

What is
\begin{equation*}
\lim _{n\rightarrow \infty } a^{n}
\end{equation*}
when $-1<a<1$?
Using this result,
what is
\begin{equation*}
\lim _{n\rightarrow \infty }\frac{a^{n} -1}{a^{n} +1}
\end{equation*}
when $-1<a<1$?
Isn't it
\begin{equation*}
\frac{\lim _{n\rightarrow \infty } a^{n} -1}{\lim _{n\rightarrow \infty } a^{n} +1}
\end{equation*}
Can you take it from here and complete the answer?

Comment: Got it! Thanks! I have a question though! Why does limit does not exist when a<0? Thanks again!

Comment: It doesnt exist for -1<a<0. Else the limit is just $-\infty $.